# Does setState() inherently affect the application performance?

Tags: flutter

I read that [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) affect application performance because it rebuilds the widget tree.

> Calling `setState` notifies the framework that the internal state of
> this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface
> in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for
> this State object.

Is this an actual concern for application performance?

Comment: If you are doing some heavy operation, separate it on different widget. and widget rebuild handle it smart way, it affects only the child is needed.  A better solution is state-management. Also use `.builder` /slivers etc. for performance

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it may but only if you are calling the function too many times unnecessarily.

**What's the best practice?**

> Try calling it at the end of functionality or only when you need to
> update the widget, you can also create multiple subclasses ( stateful
> widget), so if you want some changes in a particular area only, then
> only that widget will get updated not the entire screen.